# 2 ListAgg in the same query - resulting in 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

| rank | title | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VP | Business | 1 |
| CIO | Sales | 1 |
| CFO | Marketing | 1 |

I want a single row with comma seperated values as follows:

| rank | title | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VP, CIO, CFO | Business, Sales, Marketing | 1 |

I used `listAgg` for each field and it gives me 2 rows. How do I display in a single row?

I tried `listAgg` with 2 columns but ended up having 2 rows

```
SELECT    
    LISTAGG(
        rank,
        ','
    ) WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        rank
    ),
    LISTAGG(
        title,
        ','
    ) WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        title
    )
FROM
    test where id = 1
GROUP BY
    rank, title
ORDER BY
    id;
```

Comment: To return rows grouped by some column you obviously need to `group by <that column>`. Why did you add  `rank` and `title`  in grouping?

Answer (score 0):

It is the `GROUP BY` clause you need as well.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with temp (rank, title, id) as
  2    (select 'VP' , 'Business' , 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'CIO', 'Sales'    , 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'CFO', 'Marketing', 1 from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select listagg(rank, ', ')  within group (order by rank)  as rank,
  7         listagg(title, ', ') within group (order by title) as title,
  8         id
  9  from temp
 10  group by id;

RANK                           TITLE                                  ID
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
CFO, CIO, VP                   Business, Marketing, Sales              1

SQL>
```